# Extracting mean of sub matrices from Matlab and creating a new matrices with the means

Tags: matlab

I have a 100 X 100 matrix and I want to create a 10 x 10 matrix by taking scalar sum of the sub matrices in the bigger matrix. So scalar sum of a sub 10 x 10 matrix will be a single number which will be a element of the new 10 X 10 matrix.

I used the following code:

```
x = ones(100,100) % 100 X 100 matrix
y = []   % Output 
a = 0 ;
b = 0;
while a <=100
    while b <=100
        y = [y,sum(sum(x((a+1):(a+10),(b+1):(b+10))))];
        a=a+10; 
        b=b+10;
    end
end
reshape(y,10,10)
```

I am getting a 1 X 10 matrix instead of 100 X 100 matrix and the loop goes out of index. How do I correct the error?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what was going wrong with your code...

Comment: I am getting a 1 X 10 matrix instead of 100 X 100 matrix and the loop goes out of index

Comment: I think you mean instead of a 10 x 10 matrix. The simple way to fix the immediate problem is to change your while conditions to `while a < 100` and `while b < 100`, but then your resulting matrix is going to be transposed. I'm curious, why did you choose to use `while` loops instead of a `for` loops?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this should do what you want. Note that it calculates the sum, not the mean. If you want the mean, just change the sum to mean.

```
x = ones(100,100) % 100 X 100 matrix
y = NaN(10,10)   % Output
a = 0 ;
b = 0;
for xi=5:10:100
    for yi=5:10:100
        sub_matrix = x(xi-4:xi+5,yi-4:yi+5);
        y(ceil(xi/10),ceil(yi/10))=sum(sum(sub_matrix));
    end
end
```